# 'For' index changing because of list.pop() call

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

I have this Python code which confronts, one by one, the items in a list of integers (named 'seen' in the code posted) with all the items in the .f field of another list (named 'maxx' in the code posted).

At every iteration I'm counting (through the `c` variable) how many times does the j-th item appear in the 'maxx' list, and I want to `pop()` it from the list if it appears less than three times.

The code works perfectly, but popping an item 'pulls' any subsequent item in the 'seen' list back by one position, therefore every time the if condition is satisfied the loop misses the very next item of the list.

Here is the code:

```
for indj,j in enumerate(seen):    # every item in the 'seen' list..
    c=0
    for k in maxx:                # ..checks for a matching item in the 'maxx' list
        if j==k.f:
            c=c+1;
    if c<3:                       # if the item appears less than 3 times we pop it
        seen.pop(indj)
```

I have tried to add:

```
indj=indj-1
j=seen[indj]
```

At the end of the `if` construct, but it didn't work

Comment: Make a copy of seen before iterating: `for indj,j in enumerate(seen[:]):`. This is described in the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a new list or work with a copy. When you change a list while looping over it you skip some items. I'd do this:

```
def filter_low(lst, maxk, threshold=3):
    for item in lst:
        c = sum(1 for k in maxx if item==k.f)
        if c >= threshold:
             yield item


new_seen = list(filter_low(seen, maxk, 3))
```

Which is the same as:

```
new_seen = [item for item in seen 
            if sum(1 for k in maxx if item==k.f) >= 3]
```

You can change the original list by doing

```
seen[:] = [item for item in seen 
           if sum(1 for k in maxx if item==k.f) >= 3]
```

Comment: hey this actually did the trick (with a one-liner), why did you get a downvote? Is it inelegant to create a brand new list? Thanks anyway.

Comment: I believe that you can even change `seen[:]` to `seen`  such that you have `seen = [item for item in seen if sum(1 for k in maxx if item==k.f) >= 3]`

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the list you're iterating over is never a good idea. You could iterate over a copy and modify the actual list with

```
popped = 0
for indj, j in enumerate(seen[:]):  
    s = sum(j == k.f for k in maxx)
    if s < 3:
        seen.pop(indj - popped)
        popped += 1
```

If the `seen` list is very large, this might be inefficient.

Comment: By adding `[:]` after `seen` the code works properly (doesn't skip any items) but gives a `IndexError: pop index out of range` once it reaches the second half of the list.

Comment: Ah, of course. Adjusted the code to a new version. Try that, please.

Comment: Just to point out that setting a variable (`popped`) outside a loop and incrementing it inside the loop is considered non-pythonic. The correct method would be to do list comprehension. The reason for this is that the coder has introduced new unnecessary variables into the code (the index for example).